# Startup Disk "Reduced Security" setting effect on drive encryption

Tags: security, encryption, filevault, startup, kernel-extensions

I have a M1 Mac.  In order to install a legacy kernel extension needed for a peripheral, I have changed my startup disk security settings to "Reduced Security" as detailed here:

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-security-settings-startup-disk-a-mac-mchl768f7291/mac

My question is: does the startup disk security setting of "Reduced Security", or the installation of legacy kernel extensions, have any effect on the always on disk encryption of the startup disk?

Specifically, if I choose to wipe the disk by selecting "erase all content and settings", will the encryption keys still be securely erased?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's entirely separate from the disk encryption: it's just about whether the computer will boot from external drives or "other" OSes; and allowing kernel extensions.